# Can we emit CPU/memory metrics for a custom library running on a host?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, monitoring

Lets say we build a library, and it gets used by multiple other applications. One of the applications is also owned by me, so theoretically I have all the access to be able to emit metrics about the CPU/Memory that is being used by the library.

Are there any tools that can help with this? Is this even possible? Do note I don't need the CPU/Memory usage for the entire host/ host fleet - just the portion attributed to the library.

Additional information -

The library and application are written in Java, and run on a linux distribution, so tools compatible with the same would be helpful.

When I talk about CPU, I think about CPU Time that gets spent executing methods exposed by the library. When I talk about memory, I think about the RAM utilized by the objects that are part of that library (ignoring the other objects that may be created by the invoking, but I'm open to other interpretations of CPU/Memory Utilization that would indirectly help monitor similar performance metrics.

Comment: I think the question need clarification. Libraries lie in a shared memory space but allocated memory is generally attributed to the process using it. Regarding the target OS things can change significantly but this information is not provided as well as the context/use-case. As for the CPU, the load is always attributed to tasks (processes, threads, services, etc.). It does not make any sense to attribute that to a library. Besides, what "memory usage" is supposed to mean: throughput, req/sec, capacity?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the comment. That does make sense. As for the OS - its a Linux distribution. 

When I talk about CPU, I think about CPU Time that gets spent executing methods exposed by the library.

When I talk about memory, I think about the RAM utilized by the objects that are part of that library (ignoring the other objects that may be created by the invoking application)

Comment: The use of Java change radically the problem since Java do not use native libraries but Jitted packages in a VM unless you use JNI (not mentioned). How the segmentation of memory is supposed to be done? Package can call function of another package allocating an object but which one is supposed to be the one creating the object? If it is the last, then a package calling the standard library will not be the one creating the objects but the standard library.